# Missing Argument for Parameter 'y' in Call

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Using Xcode + Swift + SpriteKit
Heres my code:

```
let scaleMove = SKAction.moveByX(CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame)-30,y:CGRectGetMinY(self.frame)+30, duration: 5))
```

I'm not sure what to do, y has an argument. Yet it doesn't?

btw if you didn't get the error its: 'Missing Argument for Parameter 'y' in Call'

Answer (score 0):

Have a closer look on the first parameter you passing to the function, you have forgotten the closing parenthesis, you trying to pass CGPoint but it expects CGFloat and you have two parenthesis at the very end but it should be just one:

```
let scaleMove = SKAction.moveByX(
// 1st param
CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame)-30,   <- missing parenthesis and also missing y parameter for CGPoint initialisation and you cannot pass CGPoint where it expect CGFloat
// 2nd param
y:CGRectGetMinY(self.frame)+30, 
// 3th param
duration: 5))   <- too many parenthesis, remove one
```

It should be something like that:

```
let scaleMove = SKAction.moveByX(
CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame)-30,
y:CGRectGetMinY(self.frame)+30, 
duration: 5)
```